# Warning: simplexml_load_file():parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in

Tags: php, xml

Hi this is my website where I am getting these errors. The same script is working 100% fine on my localhost.

http://app.kontestic.com/kick/install.php you can see the errors on this page.

```
$dbhostname = "";
$dbusername = "";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "";
$applicationfolder = "";
if ($found) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file ( $filepath ); // line 27
    $dbhostname = (string)$xml->dbhostname; // line 28
    $dbusername = (string)$xml->dbusername;
    $dbpassword = (string)$xml->dbpassword;
    $dbname = (string)$xml->dbname;
    $applicationfolder = (string)$xml->applicationfolder;
} else {
    // Get header Location

    $REQUEST_SCHEME = (isset($_SERVER ['REQUEST_SCHEME']))?$_SERVER ['REQUEST_SCHEME']:"http";
    $SERVER_NAME = $_SERVER ['SERVER_NAME'];
    $REQUEST_URI = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
    $URI_COLL = explode ( '/', $REQUEST_URI );
    $REQUEST_URI = $URI_COLL [1];
    $headerloc = $REQUEST_SCHEME . '://' . $SERVER_NAME . '/' . $REQUEST_URI . '/setup.php';
    header ( "Location: $headerloc" );
}
```

Code for $filepath

```
$REQUEST_URI = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI_COLL = explode ( '/', $REQUEST_URI );
$REQUEST_URI = $URI_COLL [1];
$filepath = dirname ( dirname ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) ) ) .'/'. $REQUEST_URI. "/configXML.xml" ;
$found = file_exists ( $filepath );
```

Comment: Where is the initialization of $filepath in your code.

Comment: added please check it now

Comment: What is the value of file_exists ? I think there is some error in calculating $filepath. You should check both by using var_dump() on these. and just do var_dump($filepath) at line 26 also to check it.

Comment: for `var_dump ($filepath);` it is taking me to correct path of configXML.xml and for `var_dump($xml);` it says `bool(false)`

Comment: for `var_dump($applicationfolder);` its empty and showing two empty quotes

Comment: The thing is that the same script is working on my localhost

Comment: It means some illegal characters exist into your xml file. search for symbols like as "$" "&" or so on in your xml file.

Comment: Try to use same file on localhost also

Comment: YOU ARE LEGEND. Saved my a***

Comment: actually my password had illegal characters. 

Man You saved me really..............!

Comment: Thanks. Please mark that as answer. I am adding it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means some illegal characters exist into your xml file. search for symbols like as "$" "&" or so on in your xml file.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.. 
For those who are checking it in future...

1) Sometimes your password contains such symbols so make sure you dont